# Prove $\frac{1}{1+e^x}$ is Lipschitz

Tags: real-analysis

How do I prove $\frac{1}{1+e^x}$ is Lipschitz using Mean Value Theorem?

Comment: It's almost as if you were expected to prove that the derivative is bounded.

Comment: Yes, please, write out the statement of the mean value theorem and write out what Lipschitz continuous means. :)

Answer (score 1):

$HINT$

$f(x)=\frac{1}{1+e^x}$ has bounded derivative.

Indeed $$|f'(x)|=\frac{e^x}{1+2e^x+e^{2x}} \leq \frac{1}{2}$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(x) = \frac{1}{1+e^x}$.

Notice that from MVT we have
$$\left | \frac{1}{1+e^x}-\frac{1}{1+e^y}\right| = |f'(x+t(y-x))|\cdot|x-y| $$ for some $t\in (0, 1)$. But Derivative of $f$ is bounded, so that we can take the it's bound (i. e. constant $M$ such that $|f(x)|\leq M$ for all $x$) as the Lipschitz constant. And this is how you go about it in general with such functions. You usually don't use MVT, you skip to the process of checking if the derivative is bounded.

Comment: So is the derivative bounded by $\frac{1}{2}$?

Comment: Why did you write $f'(x+t(y-x))$ for some $t\in (0,1)$? Is this equivalent to writing $f'(c)$ for some $c\in(x,y)$? Is there an advantage in writing $x+t(y-x)$ instead of $c$?

Comment: @axion004 writing $x+t(x-y)$ I didn't have to assume that $x<y$. Sorry for late answer.

Comment: @axion004 another advantage I can think of, is that there's no real MVT in $\mathbb{R}^n$, but there is one for segments. Writing it this way gives a straightforward generalization, $x$ and $y$ become points in $\mathbb{R}^n$.